# escape character inside string interpolation Angular

Tags: angular, escaping, string-interpolation

I'm trying to do the following :

```
label="{{(item.nameGeneric.length === 0) ? 
    item.nameBrand : item.nameBrand (item.nameGeneric)}}"
```

The behaviour I expect is if item.nameGeneric is empty then only show nameBrand , otherwise show "namebrand (nameGeneric)".
The thing is, parenthesis inside 'else' part of the condition are being interpreted by Angular. I wan't to escape them so my final text looks like "some brand (Generic brand) in that scenario "

BTW: that's a label attribute for a checkbox and I'm using Angular 8.

Comment: Well you can just do this right: `label="{{(item.nameGeneric.length === 0) ? item.nameBrand : \`${item.nameBrand} (${item.nameGeneric})\`}}"`

Comment: I tried that one and got 'Unexpected token [`]' error

Comment: Oh well, then to it the old school way like @StepUp says: `{{ nameGeneric ? nameBrand + ' (' + nameGeneric + ') ' : nameBrand }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to concat string values:

```
label="{{(item.nameGeneric.length === 0) ? 
    item.nameBrand : (item.nameBrand + ' (' + item.nameGeneric + ' )') }}"
```

Comment: @ChristianBejarano I am glad that it helped to you!:)